# prevent this window from appearing "Update standard folders to current language?"

Tags: filemanager, localization

I'm facing an issue on my Ubuntu system where a pop-up window keeps appearing with the message, "Update standard folders to current language?" I would like to prevent this window from appearing without just clicking "Cancel." Is there a service I can disable or a command I can use to stop this window from appearing?

Your assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is there no checkmark in the dialog to not ask again?

Comment: Which Ubuntu flavor are you using? When do you see this popup? While using what program? I am guessing it is a "feature" of whatever file manager you are using, do you know which one you use? What do you see in its help->about? "Nautilus" perhaps? Or "nemo"? Something else?